# How to fix "diverged branch" in git?

Tags: git

I cloned a repository and did a checkout of a branch, and now when I do a `git pull` I see the error

```
hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.
```

Is there a way to fix this issue without rebasing or merging something? Is there some git command that will just get the local checkout to the same state as the remote repository?

I do not want to keep any local changes, I want the local branch to be EXACTLY like the remote branch which I am trying to pull. The local changes do not interest me.

There is a workaround that works fine:

```
cd ..
rm -rf repo
git clone <repo-url.git> 
cd repo
git checkout <branch>
```

but maybe there is an easier way? It took very long to remove the complete repo.

Again: I want a branch EXACTLY how it is on the remote. I do not want to merge or rebase anything. I want to have locally the exact same state of the branch as it is on the remote.

Comment: Note that "diverged" isn't *broken* (well, it is for your case, as it's not what you want, but in general it's a perfectly normal Git situation). Use [joanis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72476719/1256452).

Answer (score 15):

##### TL;DR

```
git reset --hard origin/<branchname>
```

##### Details

If you really want to discard any local changes, and just set your local branch to state of the remote, a hard reset is the thing to do.

Assuming you already have branch `<branchname>` checked out, and you want to reset it to origin's version:

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/<branchname>
```

This will discard any local commits on that branch, as well as any edits you have done locally in your sandbox. Since you're considering deleting your local sandbox altogether, I believe this is exactly what you want.

Comment: perfect answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following process works:

1. You checkout main

   ```
    git checkout main
   ```
2. Then you remove your branch

   ```
   git branch -D <branch>
   ```
3. You checkout your branch again

   ```
   git checkout <branch>
   ```
4. You do `git pull`, `git fetch`, `git st` etc. to check if all is up-to-date

Comment: Alternative: Instead of deleting the local branch, you can rename it using `git branch -m`  (and you may also want to do `git branch --unset-upstream`)