# Git fork always commits ahead I don't want

Tags: git, github

I have a fork B from an original repo A.

I also have my local (clone?) checked out version on my desktop (of B).

On my fork B, on the Git repo website it says

```
This branch is 2 commits ahead of A/master
```

So if I try and do any new pull requests, it always tries to add them in. I don't want the 2 that it thinks are ahead by (one of them was already pulled in, so I feel somehow this has got a bit messed up) :)>

I just want to get B back to sync with A and my desktop synced with that.

On my desktop I've tried things like..

```
git remote add original A
git fetch original
git checkout original
... uploads some stuff 
git checkout original
error: pathspec 'original' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

I also tried something similar earlier additionally with

```
git reset --hard origin/master
git push --force origin master
```

But nothing seems to make any difference. Either I get an error, or everything just seems the same. My forked repo is 2 commits ahead of the master, my local desktop says everything is up to date.

How do I get around this, so my remote B is synced with A, and my desktop is synced with B. Happy to lose any local work etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Part 2 of 2 ([go here for part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72480252/1256452))

#### `git push --force`

So we now know how to *move* a branch name, locally.  Now let's take another look at `git push`, and in particular, its `--force` or `-f` option.  We know that with `git push`, we normally use it to send our new commits to some other Git repository.  We then generally ask that other Git repository to *add commits to one of their branch names*.  If all we're doing is correctly adding commits, and we have permissions,<sup>7</sup> the other Git will generally accept that push request.

But the thing is that when we do send them commits, we send them *commits*, by hash ID, which string together to other commits *by hash ID*.  They don't use names internally, just hash IDs.  If we have this:

```
...--G--H   <-- main, origin/main
         \
          I--J   <-- feature1 (HEAD)
```

then our `origin/main` implies that the last time our Git talked with their Git, their last `main` commit was commit `H`.  That might still be true, but maybe—especially if this GitHub repo is *shared* with other people who run `git push`—just *maybe* somebody else has already added new commits to *their* main, so that over on GitHub, they have:

```
...--G--H--N--O--P   <-- main
```

We'll send them our `I-J` and they'll drop that into their big database,<sup>8</sup> and they will have:

```
...--G--H--N--O--P   <-- main
         \
          I--J   [proposed update]
```

Any time we tell that other Git to *move* a branch name, they're going to check if that's OK.  If we tell them to make a *new name* `feature1`, that probably would be OK, but let's say we decide, here, to ask them to set their `main`.  They will answer us back with: *No!  If I make my name `main` point to `J`, I will lose my `N-O-P` commits! That's a Big NOPe!*  Remember, they, like every Git, *find* commits by using the *branch name* to find the *last* commit and then working backwards.  `J` leads to `I` which leads to `H`, which does not lead forwards to `N`, only backwards to `G`.

This is usually how we like things like this to work.  Instead of pushing directly to their `main`, we'd push our `feature1` commits and ask them to create a *new branch* named `feature1` and that would all be OK.

But ... suppose the Git repository on GitHub is *yours*, and you had:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
```

and then you added a bad commit `I` or pair of commits `I-J` to your `main` and ran `git push origin main` and *they took them?*  Now you have:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
```

indicating that their `main` (your `origin/main`) points to commit `J`, just like your own `main`.

You now realize that `I-J` are bad and you run `git reset --hard HEAD~2` to drop these two:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/main
```

If you now run `git push origin main`, your Git will send their Git any new commits you have that they don't—i.e., none—and then ask them to set their `main` to point to `H`, and they'll *reject the request* because that will *lose* commits `I-J` off their `main`.

But that's exactly what you *want*.  You *want* them to drop the two bad commits.  So the way you make that happen is that you use `--force` or the fancier `--force-with-lease` option:

```
git push --force origin main
```

This sends the new commits (none) and then, instead *politely asking* them to make their `main` point to commit `H`, *commands* them to make their `main` point to commit `H`.  They can still refuse, but again, provided you have permissions, they'll obey this time: *Sir yes sir! `main` updated, commits ejected!*  And your Git repository will now have:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD), origin/main
         \
          I--J   [abandoned]
```

---

<sup>7</sup>Note that "base" Git doesn't have any concept of permissions to modify (push to) a branch, but most hosting servers—including GitHub—add *that* on too.

<sup>8</sup>Incoming commits actually go into a "quarantine zone" and are not migrated into the real database until they are accepted.  This feature came *from* GitHub, because GitHub used to accept everything into their databases and only then reject them and that made a big mess for GitHub.  So now there's this fancy quarantine feature.

---

#### More than one remote

Finally, we have enough to fix it all.

The first trick though is that you must, on your laptop or wherever you have your local clone, set things up so that you have *two* remotes, rather than just one.  You ran:

```
git clone <url>
```

originally, where the URL was for your fork.  Your fork is the one you want to adjust.  We must now add a remote for the repository you forked.

A remote, remember, is just a short name to hold a URL, and Git will make up remote-tracking names using this short name.  So you get to make up any name you like here.  The standard *first* name is `origin` and you already have this one.  Some people like to use `upstream` as their standard second name.  I'm not a big fan of this because Git already has something else called an *upstream*.  I'd use another name; here I'll use a silly one, but you should make up something sensible:

```
git remote add lexluthor <url>
```

Insert the URL for the repository you forked.  Then run `git fetch` to that remote:

```
git fetch lexluthor
```

You now have, in your repository on your laptop, *all of their commits* (you might already have had all of them in which case this part went fast).  You also have *remote-tracking names* for each of their *branch* names.

Now you just need to convince your GitHub fork that *its* branch `bran`, or `main`, or `master`, or whatever, should point to the *same commit* that is the `bran` or `main` or `master` or whatever commit on `lexluthor`:

```
git push --force lexluthor/master origin/master
```

That's it—that's the whole thing.  We send to `origin` any commits that we have that `origin` lacks that they need to get their (`origin`'s) branch updated: that's nothing at all because we were "two ahead" and none at all behind.  Then we *command* the Git over on GitHub to make our `origin`'s `master` identify the same *commit* that our `lexluthor/master` identifies, which is the commit that `master` identifies in the repository you forked originally.

You probably *also* want your own `master` to drop the two commits you're ahead.  You might want to keep those commits for some other reason / to put on another branch / whatever; for that:

```
git switch master
git status
# make sure it says "nothing to commit, working tree clean"
# if not, make a new commit now
git branch keep-extras
git reset --hard lexluthor/master
```

and now your `master` is in sync with both `lexluthor` and `origin`.  Note that you could have used `origin/master` in the `git reset` line.

What we did was really simple.  We just had to go around and around and do it the long way.  That's Git for you!

Answer (score 3):

## Part 1 of 2 ([go here for part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72480346/1256452))

You've kind of jumped into a somewhat-advanced setup.  There are *three* Git repositories you need to worry about here, not *two*, and GitHub "forks" are clones with some special properties.  (Note that plain Git does not have forks and pull requests—these are GitHub add-ons.  Other hosting sites also have fork add-ons and/or pull requests and/or merge requests: they are pretty common as add-ons.  But none of them are in base Git.)

#### What you need to know to get started

Git is a *Distributed Version Control System* or DVCS.  Git achieves its "distributed" effect by having multiple *repositories*, which Git calls *clones*.  So you're going to need to know several things:

- What, exactly, is a repository?
- What does *cloning* a repository do?
- What special things does a GitHub fork have that a clone doesn't?

We'll come back to the other two after we expand the first one just a bit.  There's a lot more we *could and should* say but I've run out of space and have to split this up anyway...

#### A repository is mostly two databases

A *Git repository* is made up of two big databases, plus a lot of smaller ancillary items.  The two databases are the important things, and one of them is usually much bigger, and is always much more important:

- The bigger / more-important database is Git's *object* database.  This holds Git *commits* and other internal Git objects.  Everything inside this database has an *OID* or Object ID, which I prefer to call a *hash ID* (you'll see both terms, plus the now-outdated term SHA-1, referring to one specific kind of hash algorithm Git uses to get its hash IDs).

  The important entity for *you* in this big database is the *commit*.  A Git repository could be—and can be, except for the annoyance of it that we'll see below—nothing about this database full of commits (plus their supporting objects).  As such, you'll need to know exactly what a commit is, but we'll leave that for the next section.

  Each object—hence each commit—gets an ID.  Commits in particular get a *unique* ID: when you make a new commit, you get an ID that has never been used before, anywhere, in *any* Git repository anywhere in the universe.  When I make a new commit, *I* get a unique ID.  Everyone's new commit always gets a *new* ID.  This part is the true magic of Git and enables its distributed nature, and it's also mathematically impossible and certainly doomed.<sup>1</sup>  Fortunately, the sheer massive *size* of commit hash IDs is so big that the day of doom is probably trillions of years off, long after not only you and I are dead, but the universe itself has more or less expired.

  In order to fish a commit *out* of the database, Git *needs* this hash ID.  If that database were all there was in a repository, we'd all have to memorize hash IDs all the time.  So...
- The other, usually much smaller database holds *names:* branch names, tag names, and all other kinds of names.  Each name holds *one* hash ID, which is all that's needed because of the clever design of a commit, which we'll get to in a moment.

Git stores certain hash IDs that it needs into the *names* database, under names that we (humans) choose.  Then we (humans) just provide Git a *name*, like a branch name, and Git uses that to fish out the big ugly random-looking hash ID *Git* needs, to obtain the commit.

So a repository consists of these two databases: one full of commits and other supporting objects, and one with names, so that humans don't have to memorize hash IDs.

---

<sup>1</sup>See the [pigeonhole principle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72476719/1256452) for details.  On a simple basis, the fact that the hash ID is already spread pretty evenly across a 160-bit space reduces the collision chance to infinitesimal, but alas, the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) rears *its* ugly head in turn, so once you have enough quadrillions of commits, it's more like the chance of having your computer explode, which [actually can happen](https://www.cio.com/article/261213/laptop-computers-dell-to-recall-4-1m-batteries-due-to-fire-hazard.html).  (OK, "sort of" explode. )  But in practice we're safe, especially because we can relax that "completely unique" constraint slightly most of the time.  Git is also moving to a 256-bit hash, which will make us even safer.

---

#### What's in a commit

*Commits* are, in the end, the reason we use Git.  We don't use Git because of branching—though we use things called branches to *organize* our commits, and as noted above, we use things called *branch names* to *find a specific commit* (and Git beats the poor word "branch" practically to death by confusingly using the word for at least three different purposes, which is why it's often a good idea to try to avoid the bare word *branch*).  Git isn't about *files* either, but each commit does *store* files, because the while the commit is Git's unit-of-storage, humans really care a lot about individual files.  We also like Git's various features like merging and cherry-picking and so on; but these features all hinge on commits.  The big database *stores* commits and it's the *commits* that matter, at least to Git.

You therefore need to know *exactly* what a commit is and does for you.  You already know that (like all Git objects) it has a hash ID.  It's also worth mentioning that, to make the distributed thing work, these hash IDs can *never change*, and to make *that* work, Git says that nothing *in* a commit can ever *be* changed either.  If we don't like some commits, we can make other (new and improved) commits we use *instead*, but we can't actually *fix* the bad ones.  Fortunately, commits themselves are ridiculously cheap, despite what they hold:

- Every commit has a *full snapshot* of every source file (that Git knew about at the time you, or whoever, made that commit, that is).  The files *in* the commit are stored in a special, read-only, compressed and *de-duplicated* format, that only Git can read and literally nothing—not even Git itself—can overwrite.
- Each commit stores some *metadata*, or information about this particular commit.  That includes the name and email address of the person who made the commit, for instance, and some date-and-time stamps.

The de-duplication means that each new commit doesn't need to store all the files, even though it stores all the files.  In particular, suppose you change a file slightly, and make a new commit.  The new commit has to store the updated file, but can refer back to all the unchanged files.  Then you change the same file *back* and commit again.  This second new commit is new, so it gets another ID, but this time *every file is a duplicate* so it literally takes *no space* to store them.

The metadata is at least slightly different every time though.  For instance, each commit gets a time stamp of "now" (there are ways to tweak this but let's not worry about this here), so since time is always increasing, every commit gets a different time-stamp for instance, even if everything else is the same (author and committer, snapshot, and so on).  This stuff gets compressed too—just like files—so it may take very little actual space, and that is why commits are so cheap: they're *mostly* just one of those big ugly hash IDs, plus a few bytes for whatever else is unique about that particular commit (including another hash ID as we're about to see).

To this metadata, Git adds its own thing: each commit stores, in its metadata, a *list of previous commit hash IDs*.  Most commits store just one hash ID.  Git calls this the *parent* of the new commit, and that one parent is the commit we used when we *made* that new commit.

When something stores the hash ID of a commit, we say that the something *points to* the commit.  We can draw that as an arrow, pointing to the commit.  So let's suppose we have a tiny three-commit repository.  Each of the three commits has some big ugly unique hash ID that we won't try to remember or pronounce or anything: instead, we'll call the first one "commit `A`", the second "commit `B`", and the third "commit `C`".  Let's draw them:

```
A <-B <-C
```

Here, commit `C` *points to* its parent commit `B`, which was the current commit when we made `C`.  `B` in turn points back to its parent `A`.  But `A` was the very first commit: there was no commit before `A`, so its list of parent hash IDs is empty, and it doesn't point anywhere.

Now, Git *needs* the hash ID of `C` in order to *find* commit `C`.  But as we said before, Git will have a *branch name* hold that hash ID.  The name will *point to* `C`, like this:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
```

(assuming the branch name is `main`).

The name `main` literally holds the *latest commit* hash ID.  That lets Git find `C` quickly.  Commit `C` holds the hash ID of the previous commit (points to its parent) `B`, which in turn points to `A`, which doesn't point anywhere, and that—going `C`, then `B`, then `A` in that order—*is* the history in the repository.

The history, in other words, is the commits; the commits are the history.  The commits themselves are completely immutable, too, but we *find* the commit using a *branch name*, and those *are* mutable, so if we decide that we really hate commit `C` for some reason, we can eject it and make a new-improved commit `D` that points directly back to `B`:

```
     C   [ejected]
    /
A--B--D   <-- main
```

With no *name* by which to *find* commit `C`, it will seem to be gone; if we haven't memorized hash IDs, commit `C` will *seem* to have changed, and humans don't memorize hash IDs so we've successfully "rewritten history" at this point.

#### Working tree, index, current branch, and adding commits

Before we move on to distributed version control, let's mention a few other things:

- The *commits* are completely read-only.  Moreover, only Git can read these files.  To get any work done, we need ordinary, readable *and writable* files.  To get there, we'll *check out* a commit by *switching to* some branch name.  This selects the *most recent* commit, as pointed-to by the branch name, and *copies the files out of the commit* into a working area.
- The working area, which has usable versions of the files in it, is what you see as you work in Git.  Git calls this your *working tree* or *work-tree* for short.  *These files are not actually **in** Git!*  They were extracted *from* Git, but as you work on them, they drift away from what Git had.
- Git keeps an extra "copy" (in the de-duplicated form) of each file in another area that Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.  The reason you have to `git add` files all the time is to get Git to update its staged "copies".  We'll come back to this when we make a new commit below.
- Because we can have more than one branch *name*, Git needs a way to know which *name* you're using.  Because Git always has a *current commit*,<sup>2</sup> Git also needs a way to know which *commit* you're using.  Git combines these two needs into one thing: a special name, `HEAD`.

The special name `HEAD` is *attached to* the *current branch name*, and the branch name in turn points to the *current commit*.  So if we have:

```
A--B--C   <-- main (HEAD)
```

this means that `git status` will say `on branch main`, because `HEAD` is attached to `main`: our current *branch name* is `main`.  Meanwhile our current *commit* is commit `C`, because `main` points to `C`.

Let's make a second name, `develop`.  A branch name in Git must point to some existing commit.  We only have the three, so we have to pick one of these three to have `develop` point to it.  Git's default is to point to the *current* commit, which—*by definition*—is also the *latest* commit for the current branch.  So we'll get this:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop, main (HEAD)
```

We now have two names for commit `C`.  Commits `A-B-C` are on *both branches* (all at the same time).  Our *current name* is still `main`.

If we now run `git switch develop` or `git checkout develop`, Git will remove, from our working area (and its index), all the committed files from `C` as found by `main`, and swap in all the files from the commit we're moving to as found by `develop`, i.e., commit `C`.<sup>3</sup>  The end result is this:

```
A--B--C   <-- develop (HEAD), main
```

We can now do some work, and `git add` and `git commit` as usual.  The commit command will:

- gather any necessary metadata (`user.name` and `user.email` for instance);
- figure out the current commit's hash ID (whatever `C` really is);
- get a log message to put in the new commit;
- make a snapshot from whatever is in Git's index / staging-area (this is why you had to `git add`); and
- turn all of that into a new commit, which we'll call commit `D`.

The new commit will point back to the current commit `C`:

```
A--B--C
       \
        D
```

but now we have the *clever* part of `git commit`: Git shoves the new commit's *hash ID* into the *current name*.  So branch name `develop`, to which `HEAD` is attached, now points to `D`.  Branch name `main` is left alone, so it still points to `C`:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
       \
        D   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

If we switch back to `main`, we get:

```
A--B--C   <-- main (HEAD)
       \
        D   <-- develop
```

Git removes the commit-`D` files from our working tree and its index/staging-area, puts in the commit-`C` files instead, and lets us get to work.  If we now make a new commit `E` we get this:

```
        E   <-- main (HEAD)
       /
A--B--C
       \
        D   <-- develop
```

and now you can see the "branching" in action.  Commits `A-B-C` are still on both branches, but commit `D` is only on `develop` and `E` is only on `main`, at least at the moment.

Since branch names move, the set of commits "on" any given branch changes as the names move.  And, since we can create and destroy branch names at will, the set of *branches* that *contain* any given commit changes, too.  **What never changes is the commits themselves.  What does change is the *set of commits we find* by starting from the *last* one, as found by the name, and working backwards.**

What we'll be doing in a moment is manipulating names.

---

<sup>2</sup>There is an exception to this rule, in a new and totally empty repository: here there are no commits at all, so there cannot be a current commit either.  This exception is how we got commit `A`, with no parent, in the first place.  You can re-create the exceptional situation to make additional *root commits* but we're not going to cover this here.

<sup>3</sup>This seems really dumb: why remove and replace files with themselves?  And it is dumb, and Git doesn't do it *in this case*.  That is, Git is clever about which files need to be removed and replaced, and only does the ones that *need* it.  If you're moving "from `C` to `C`" like this, *no* files need it, and Git doesn't bother doing anything at all.  This becomes important later, but if you *start out* thinking of this as "swap out each file from the old commit for the one from the new commit" you're in much better shape: you can add the optimization in your head later.

---

#### Clones and forks

Git has the concept of a clone: we run:

```
git clone <url>
```

and get a *copy* of something.  But what exactly do we copy?  The whole process starts by having Git make for us a new, empty repository, so we have a new empty Git-objects database and a new empty names-database (and also an empty working tree and index / staging-area).  But Git immediately reaches out, using the supplied URL, to make an "Internet phone call" to what should be more Git software.  That software answers the "call" and looks up some existing Git repository: a database full of commits-and-other-objects, plus a names database.

The `git clone` command has the *other* Git software list out *their* names.  Our Git therefore gets to see their branch and tag and other names.  Now our Git does something funny with these names, which we'll get back to in a moment; but each of these names comes with a hash ID too, and at least for *branch* names, those represent the *latest* commits, as found in the other Git repository objects database.

At this point, our Git is going to get from their Git every commit they have that we don't.  (There is a bunch of protocol involved here that allows us to make a single-branch or shallow clone, which we'll ignore, and some other special cases that we'll also ignore, to keep this simple.)  We of course have a totally-empty database, so that's *every commit*.  So they package up every commit (plus all necessary supporting objects) and ship those over, and our Git unpacks those into our big database.

We now have *all their commits*, but *no branches*.  Now our Git does the funny thing: for each of their *branch* names, our Git *changes* this name into a *remote-tracking name*.  (Our Git takes their tag names unchanged, so if they have a `v1.0`, we get a `v1.0` tag too, at least by default; again, there are some control knobs for this, but we'll ignore them here.)  These remote-tracking names work a lot like branch names, but they are our Git's *memory* of *their* Git's *branch* names.  They're not actually *branch* names at all.

So, if they have a `main` and a `develop`, for instance, we'll get an `origin/main` and `origin/develop`.  Our Git makes the remote-tracking name by sticking `origin`—a *remote*, or a short name for that other Git repository, saving the URL—and a slash in front of each of their branch names.<sup>4</sup>

At the end of this particular process, then, we have this:

- our commits-and-objects database has every commit they have;
- our names database has *no* branches, just a bunch of remote-tracking names.

Git is perfectly capable of functioning this way—*Git* doesn't really *need* the branch names—but it's too annoying for normal humans to work this way, so now `git clone` takes two last steps:

- it creates one branch name, and then
- it checks out that branch, so that this is our current branch and commit.

The name of the branch that `git clone` creates here is the name we gave it on the command line, when we ran `git clone -b branch url`.  But we probably didn't run with `-b` at all.  In this case, our Git software asks their Git software which branch name *they* recommend, which must be one of their branch names, and hence one of our remote-tracking names.  Our Git then pretends that's what we asked for with `-b`.

Our Git will now create, in our repository, *one* branch name, from the `-b` or implied `-b`.  The commit that this branch will select is the *same* commit our corresponding remote-tracking name selects, which is the commit their branch of the *same name* selects.  If this seems like a very roundabout way to do a simple thing, well, that's Git for you.

We end up with *one branch name*, but it's *our* branch, not theirs.  It's just *spelled the same* as one of their branch names.  This whole notion—that **just because two branch names are *spelled* the same, does not mean they *are* the same**—becomes very important in a moment.

But what about GitHub's big green <kbd>FORK</kbd> button?  What does that do?  Well, a fork is just a GitHub side clone, with two differences and some added features:

- There's no index and working tree on GitHub.  You're going to have to clone your fork so that you can get work done.
- They copy *all* the original repository's *branch* names to branch names in your fork: there's no such thing as a *remote-tracking* name.

The added features include the ability to make pull requests (plus all the usual GitHub features of issues and code reviews and the like).  Your new clone, on GitHub, is mostly-permanently linked to the original repository on GitHub.<sup>5</sup>  GitHub also do some sneaky / clever tricks behind the scenes to save themselves a ton of disk space here: this makes the GitHub fork operation relatively cheap for GitHub to do.<sup>6</sup>

---

<sup>4</sup>Technically, the remote-tracking name are in a separate [*namespace*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace), so even if we make a local branch with `origin/` in its name, *Git* won't get confused.  But *we* probably will, so don't do that.

<sup>5</sup>The *mostly* here is just because it's possible for whoever *had* the original repository to *remove* it.  When this happens, GitHub pass "fork ownership" across a chain of linked repositories internally: it's all a little complicated, but not something users have to worry about, as GitHub take care of it all internally.

<sup>6</sup>This is also something users don't normally need to concern themselves with, but it disables Git's `git gc` mechanism that eventually removes unused commits.  This means that if you accidentally push a commit to GitHub that contains sensitive data, you *must* get GitHub admins to help remove it: you cannot fix this yourself.  Even if they ever change this, it would still be a good idea to contact them though: there's inevitably a delay in gc removing unneeded / unwanted Git objects, and a big hosting site like GitHub would schedule this to happen infrequently to keep their own load lighter.

---

#### Updating a clone

Now that we have all these clones, we need to look at the mechanisms Git offers for updating them.  There are really just two:

- `git fetch` has your Git call up another Git and *get stuff from them*.
- `git push` has your Git call up another Git and *offer stuff to them*.

The `git pull` command, which I recommend that newbies avoid initially, just means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command to make use of the stuff we got*.  The reason to avoid this initially is to learn precisely how to use the various second-command options, including what can go wrong and how to recover from that.  (After that, you may find situations where you want to insert commands *between* the two, and still avoid `git pull`, and/or you may find that the convenience `git pull` two-in-one command is convenient for you, and you can safely use it then.)  So even with `git pull` we still just have the two operations, fetch and push.

These two operations are different.  It's not just the direction of transfer, though obviously that matters:

- `git fetch` *gets* stuff and *adds it to your repository*.  But it also works with those remote-tracking names.  When you get stuff from the Git you're calling `origin`, your Git software updates your repository's memory of *their* repository's branch names.  So your remote-tracking names get updated.

  After a successful `git fetch`, you'll usually want to do something to *make use of* the fetched commits.  (This is why `git pull` exists: it seems Linus Torvalds originally assumed everyone would *always* want to do that *right away*.  The `git pull` command was the only user-oriented "get stuff" command, and there were no remote-tracking names.  There were no remotes!  This all turned out to be a bad idea, and remotes and remote-tracking names got invented, but now we have the awkward situation of having `fetch` as the opposite of `push`, with `pull` being the overpowered does-two-things command.)
- `git push` *sends* stuff and (tries to) add it to *their* repository.  But:

  - They may refuse to add it.
  - If they *do* add it, there's no equivalent of a remote-tracking name: you tell them to add commits to their branch or branches, and they do that, and now *their branch* has new commits added.  There's no "and now combine them" step.  *You* must have everything *pre-combined*.

There's a lot more to know here, but for now we'll stop at this point, because we finally have enough to tackle your particular problem.  Let's do some review first though, and make particular note of something we went by very fast earlier.

#### "Resetting" a branch name

Suppose you have, in your repository, these branch names and commits:

```
          I--J   <-- feature1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- feature2 (HEAD)
```

That is, you've been working on two features.  You made two commits for `feature1`, both of which come right after the last commit on `main`.  Let's say that they're both just fine and you want to keep them.  But then you made two commits on `feature2`, also just after the last commit on `main`, and you've been testing commit `L` and have discovered that it's bad.  So you want to be rid of it.

We mentioned earlier that we can boot a commit off the end of a chain, but we showed a *replacement* for it at that time.  Let's look at the mechanism behind booting out a commit now.  What we need to do is make the *name* `feature2` *point to* commit `K` instead of commit `L`.  This will "abandon" commit `L`: it will still be in the big all-objects database, but because we *find* commits by starting at the *end and working backwards*, making the "last" commit on `feature2` be `K` instead of `L` makes it appear as though `L` is actually gone:

```
          I--J   <-- feature1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K   <-- feature2 (HEAD)
           \
            L   [abandoned]
```

How do we get this to happen?  In Git, we use `git reset` to adjust the *current branch name*.

The `git reset` command is big and complicated: it does way too many things.  But for our particular case, we can use it in a simple mode, running:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

The `--hard` tells `git reset` to wipe out what's in Git's index / staging-area and what's in our working tree even as it moves the branch name.  The `HEAD~1` here means: *find the current commit, then step back one hop*.  Instead of `HEAD~1` we can run `git log` and grab the raw hash ID of commit `K` with the mouse:

```
git reset --hard a123456
```

or whatever.  Sometimes using copy-paste with `git log` is the way to go here; sometimes relative expressions like `HEAD~1` or `HEAD^` are easier; but either way, the key concept is this: **`git reset` makes the *current branch name* point to any commit we pick.**  We just pick some commit, by any name that finds it, and hand that to `git reset` and `git reset` makes the *current name*—the one `HEAD` is attached to—point to that commit.

(To undo a "wrong" `git reset`, we would just run `git reset --hard hash-of-L` here, but do that, we have to be able to *find* the hash of commit `L`.  If it's on your screen, you can use copy-paste.  If not, where will you get it?  Git has a bunch of ways to get these back for a while, so it's not impossible, it's just hard and annoying.  Note though that `--hard` means *wipe out my working tree by overwriting all the files with the ones from the newly selected commit*.  Since your working tree files are *not in Git*, Git won't be able to help you get them back.  Be *very sure* about this before using `--hard`: run `git status` a lot!)

We can also move a branch name that is *not* the current branch.  Suppose, having ejected `L`, we realize that commit `J` is bad too.  We could run:

```
git checkout feature1
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

to eject `J`, but we could also just run:

```
git branch -f feature1 feature1~1
```

The `git branch` command can—when used with the `-f` or `--force` option—move *any branch name other than the current branch*, to any commit, the same way that `git reset` moves the *current* branch to any commit.  (The `--force` option is required so that you don't accidentally move an existing branch name when you though you were creating a new branch name, but had a typo or brain-o or whatever.)